# Validation error An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I had a html form with set of input fields for each of which I am giving `required="true"` for validation. But when I click on submit after entering the mandatory fields it is give an error:

> An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable

I know if we use `novalidate` to the form I wont get that error, but my validation wont work. How can I make my validation work without error?

```
 <form name="customerForm" class="form-horizontal" id="custForm">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="customerName" class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input class="form-control" ng-model="$root.customerDetails.customerName" placeholder="Enter customer name" type="text" required="true" value = "{{customerName}}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="postCode" class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1  control-label">Post code</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input class="form-control" ng-model="$root.customerDetails.address.postcode" placeholder="Enter post code" type="text" value = "{{postCode}}">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <button type="next" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$ctrl.findAddress()">Find address</button>      
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="selectAddress" class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1  control-label">Select address</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <select class="form-control" id="selectAddress" ng-model="$ctrl.quote.newClient.customerAddress" ng-change="$ctrl.populateAddressFields()">
                    <option ng-repeat="address in addresses"
                      value="{{address}}" >{{address}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="form-group ng-hide">
            <label for="textArea" class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1  control-label">Address</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <textarea ng-model="$ctrl.quote.newClient.customerAddress" class="form-control" rows="3" required="true"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="address1" class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1  control-label">Address 1</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input class="form-control" ng-model="$root.customerDetails.address.addressLine1" placeholder="Enter Address 1" type="text" required="true" value = "{{addressLine1}}">
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="address2" class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1 control-label">Address 2</label>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <input class="form-control" ng-model="$root.customerDetails.address.addressLine2" placeholder="Enter Address 2" type="text" required="true" value = "{{addressLine2}}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1  control-label">Email address</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input class="form-control" ng-model="$root.customerDetails.eMail" placeholder="Enter customer email" type="email" required="true" value = "{{emailId}}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="customerMobile" class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1  control-label">Mobile number</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input class="form-control" ng-model="$root.customerDetails.customerMobile" placeholder="Enter customer mobile number" type="text" required="true">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-show="$root.customerDetails.tradeType.description == 'Limited Company'">
            <label for="inputCompanyRegistrationNumber" class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1  control-label">Company registration number</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input class="form-control" ng-model="$root.customerDetails.companyRegNo" placeholder="Enter company registration number" type="text" required="true">
            </div>
        </div>
     </fieldset>
 </form>
```

And Iam using `$valid` to validate the form

```
<div class="col-lg-1">
     <button form="custForm" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary right-button" ng-click="customerForm.$valid && $ctrl.proceedToPaymentDetails()">Next</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: This happens when you have hidden fields that you are attempting to validate.  If they're hidden as they're not required then disable them as well.  That will stop validation trying to give them focus.

Comment: NO I dont have any such fields

Comment: You don't have any hidden fields?  You don't have any fields inside elements with the class `.ng-hide`?

Comment: You do have some ng-show directives. Could you make a live exemple (codepen, pluckr ..) to help see the problem in action ?